# Download images asynchronously and identify which image has downloaded?

Tags: ios, core-data, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I have multiple images to download and then save them in Core-data later. I have successfully downloaded all the images using NSURLConnection. Image Array consist of dictionaries which has values for id, entity name and imagePath. Once I downloaded how can I update Core-data store with specific image data? Since

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

method doesn't include any information about image downloaded, so I couldn't update Core-data. What should I do achieve this kind of functionality? any alternative ways to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the `NSURL` from the request in the given connection. From the url you should be able to figure out which image it is.